# React error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React version: 16.13.1

So I was following a tutorial on React. I created an app with create react app and wrote this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    content: 'HTML is easy',
    date: '2019-05-30T17:30:31.098Z',
    important: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: 'Browser can execute only Javascript',
    date: '2019-05-30T18:39:34.091Z',
    important: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: 'GET and POST are the most important methods of HTTP protocol',
    date: '2019-05-30T19:20:14.298Z',
    important: true
  }
]

const App = (props) => {
  const { notes } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>{notes[0].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[1].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[2].content}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App notes={notes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

export default App;
```

and I'm getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" at the beginning of the line `<li>{notes[0].content}</li>`

Comment: This code works as-is. https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-sky-cudqr

Comment: Well it also works in the tutorial, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe you've made a typo elsewhere, or the problem is something else that you've not included in your question. That said, without a [mcve], we can't help.

Comment: You can just remove this line:   `const { notes } = props`. Notes is just a constant, not a prop.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to pass props, You will get notes directly

```
// const { notes } = props //skip this line
```

Comment: While it's true in OP's code, it's not really helping since it's a tutorial and in any real use-case, the data won't be hard-coded in the same file as the component!

Comment: That's fair, deleting this line does in fact make my code work. Still no idea why tho

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing wrong with the code you showed here, you might want to check if there's a problem somewhere else, you can try running the code you sent in an isolated react environment to be sure of what I'm saying

Also, notes is a global constant so if you only need it for the App component, you don't have to pass it as a prop, you can just use it directly in the App component

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are trying to achieve here, you want to have default props but once a props is passed to the component, you want to override the default props.

You can do this with a conditional statement and not destructing that way.

That line of code already overrides the default with an undefined value.

Find the correction below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    content: "HTML is easy",
    date: "2019-05-30T17:30:31.098Z",
    important: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: "Browser can execute only Javascript",
    date: "2019-05-30T18:39:34.091Z",
    important: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: "GET and POST are the most important methods of HTTP protocol",
    date: "2019-05-30T19:20:14.298Z",
    important: true,
  },
];

const App = (props) => {
  if (props.notes) {
    notes = props.notes;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>{notes[0].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[1].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[2].content}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App notes={notes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

export default App;
```